# What is the formal definition of an algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to find a formal definition of an algorithm but I only found [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Algorithm/Formal_Specification). I don't know if it is the accepted one, or even the only one, and I would like some literature on the formal definition(s?). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:

I'm asking about the formal mathematical definition, not the definition of a sequence of reproducible steps that given some input, produces some output.

Comment: The page you found cites [1997: Donald E. Knuth: The Art of Computer Programming: Volume 1: Fundamental Algorithms (3rd ed.)], have you checked this book?

Comment: There is no single mathematical definition. Pick any of the available formalisms: TMs, RAMs, WHILE programs, ...